# Monodevelop migrate 2.8 didn't add .h files

Tags: xcode, xcode4, xamarin.ios, migrate

I just upgrade my MonoDevelop to the latest version (2.8). I also installed XCode4, since it's fully supported now. When opening my solution (which consists of several projects) I was asked to migrate my solution. I did this and saved everything.

However, I think something is missing. When I open the .xib file, the project on the right doesn't show .h files, like shown in the [tutorial](http://docs.xamarin.com/@api/deki/files/261/=Transitioning_from_Xcode_3_to_Xcode_4_in_Monotouch.pdf).

It also shows warnings that the outlets were not found in XCode.

When I add a new screen, it creates the .h file as it should and shows this in XCode. However all existing screens don't have these files, which makes it impossible to add/change outlets.

How can I fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that your classes you expect to see in Xcode have explicit `[Register("SomeName")]` attributes, which register them with a name usable from Xcode/Obj-C/IB.

I would expect an imported project to have those attributes already, since they're required for xibs to be able to load the classes by name, but you could maybe have got away without those attributes by using outlets on "File's Owner".

Comment: Hello. The register was in the designer.cs. Moving it towards the .cs actually resolved the issue of the missing .h file. However he now puts the .h file in the wrong folder. I have my view-controllers and xib files in subfolders (i.e. a Employee-folder for views regarding employees).

Why are the .h files stored in the "root" folder, instead of the correct subfolder?

Comment: The h files just reflect the types, not the physical file(s) they're defined in, so the location doesn't really matter. But I agree it's a little unexpected, so I filed an enhancement bug: http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1390